# Is it possible in Spring Kafka to send a messages that will expire on a per message (not per template or higher) basis

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to use Kafka as a request-response system between two clients much like RabbitMQ and I was wondering if it is possible to set the expiration of a message so that after it is posted it will automatically get deleted from the Kafka servers.

I'm trying to do it on a per message level as well (but even if it were per-topic it is okay, but I'd like to use the same template if possible).

I was checking ProducerRecord, but all it had was timestamp.  I also don't see any mention of it in KafkaHeaders

Answer (score 1):

Kafka records are deleted in segments (a group of messages) based on overall *topic retention*.

Spring is just a client. It doesn't control the server side logic of the log cleaner.

Comment: Correct. Kafka has no "per record TTL"; you can only set the retention time at the broker or topic level.